# How to delete a row based on the final numbers of a column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have df1 that looks like:

```
        Stabr  Area_name    trucks FIPS   cars accidents
    1    US  United States  13.1    0       0      0
    2    AL        Alabama  16.8   1000     0      0
    3    AL Autauga County  13.8   52000    17     0
    4    AL Baldwin County  9.8    4000     33     0
    5    AL Barbour County  30.9   1230     0      0
    6    AL    Bibb County  21.8   1700     0      0
```

I would like to delete all rows that have have 0 as a value in `FIPS` and all rows that have the final three digits = `000` in `FIPS` . I was thinking that would just be checking to see if `FIPS` = 0, or if it is divisible by 1000. Is there a way to do this?

Output should look like:

```
        Stabr  Area_name    trucks FIPS   cars accidents
    5    AL Barbour County  30.9   1230     0      0
    6    AL    Bibb County  21.8   1700     0      0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can keep the row if `FIPS` not equal to 0 and if `FIPS` is not divisible by 1000.

```
subset(df, FIPS != 0 & FIPS %% 1000 != 0)

#  Stabr     Area_name trucks FIPS cars accidents
#5    AL BarbourCounty   30.9 1230    0         0
#6    AL    BibbCounty   21.8 1700    0         0
```

Actually, you could check only for 1000 since `0/1000` would give 0.

```
subset(df, FIPS %% 1000 != 0)
```

Comment: I'm curious how the answerer becomes the asker. Is this part of the software update yesterday?

Comment: You mean on the home page of StackOverflow? Yeah, it's been there for some time now. I was confused by it too but if you look at it closely it shows "answered" and not "asked" as it would normally show. Also there is "modified" when you edit the post.

Comment: Good to know, cause I was wondering why a guy with 135k rep had so many basic questions. And, thanks for your very interesting responses.